# Requiring unknown module "undefined" on react-native-maps

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to implement react-native-maps from [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps).
But when I import MapView above on `App.js` with the code `import MapView from 'react-native-maps';` I get this error:

> Requiring unknown module "undefined".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environement).

My `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "MyNewProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "react": "16.3.0-rc.0",
    "react-native": "0.54.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-rc.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your package.json ? Did you try to restrat the react-native packager ? Did you linked the module properly ? (see how to https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

Comment: yes i did but error exist again, my package.json is updated at my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this from your package.json `"react-native-maps": "^0.20.1"` into this "react-native-maps": "https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps.git"` to ensure that you will use the master branch as suggested here https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2051#issuecomment-371530715