# Requiring unknown module "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In Release Build of android i get this error in debug all working fine.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules. Requiring unknown module
>   "undefined".

Please help me. i stuck on this still 6 hours

```
"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-dropdown": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-geo-fencing": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-marker": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-share": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

[Requiring unknown module "undefined" on react-native-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588806/requiring-unknown-module-undefined-on-react-native-maps)
this is too old solution its not work for me .

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18179)?

Comment: did you managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

First run command:

```
rm -rf /node_modules && npm install
```

then run:

```
react-native start
```