# Requiring unknown module: "undefined"

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, node-modules

The react native app runs just fine in a **Debug** configuration but crashes when I build for **Release**, with Xcode giving:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined"., stack:
h@2:1417
d@2:958
B@660:5322
Ar@91:41759
yl@91:51609
ti@91:78509
ei@91:78437
Za@91:78202
qa@91:75364
qa@(null):(null)
<unknown>@91:26064
<unknown>@189:3806
Ct@91:26011
Pt@91:25946
Oa@91:72858
al@91:47559
al@(null):(null)
<unknown>@660:4257
dispatchEvent@125:5675
<unknown>@138:3390
value@24:896
value@39:3492
<unknown>@39:747
value@39:2538
value@39:719
value@(null):(null)
```

Here are my dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "jsdom-jscore-rn": "github:iamcco/jsdom-jscore-rn#master",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-circular-slider": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-notifications": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "rn-circular-slider": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

<s>I suspect that it's [jsdom-jscore-rn](https://github.com/iamcco/jsdom-jscore-rn) that's causing the issue because it has cyclic dependencies. (It crashes after the login screen redirects to a screen that uses this module)</s>

It may also be worth noting that I'm using an offline bundle generated using:

`npx react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios  --assets-dest iOS`

**How do I debug this error or at least make sense of where this error is coming from? Are there line numbers I can look at? How do resolve this without having to disable this module completely?**

**Update: Fixed. See answer.**

---

A clean install of node modules hasn't helped and older threads: [Requiring unknown module “undefined” on react-native-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588806/requiring-unknown-module-undefined-on-react-native-maps), [Requiring unknown module “undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199000/requiring-unknown-module-undefined) haven't helped either.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I was able to fix it. The problem wasn't related to node_modules at all.

The real problem:

```
<Image source={require('./assets/image.png')} />
```

The image wasn't getting included when I built for Release. Fixed it by adding the image manually to xcassets (iOS) and changing that line to:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'image' }} />
```